# Why don't I need to statically import launch method?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I was tinkering with the smallest runnable JavaFX application I could create. I came up with this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// import static javafx.application.Application.launch; // not needed ! WHY?

public class SmallestJavaFXExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.show();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Apparently this compiles with JDK 8. But to my surprise the static import of the launch method is not needed. But when I test this with Eclipse, its compiler says that it cannot find the launch method.

Why don't I need the static import for launch?

Comment: Please stop deleting the text of your question. It will be closed if the community decides it's not worth keeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `extend` a class, you automatically inherit the static methods of the parent classes too.